# Return a local object rvalue reference,right or wrong?

Tags: c++, c++11

I see once return a local object,the compiler will take the return value optimization.(RVO,NRVO).

> The part of the Standard blessing the RVO goes on to say that if the
>   conditions for the RVO are met, but compilers choose not to perform
>   copy elision, the object being returned must be treated as an rvalue.

So we just write code like this:

```
Widget makeWidget() 
{
 Widget w;
 …
 return w;//never use std::move(w);
}
```

I never see somebody write code like this:

```
Widget&& makeWidget()
{
 Widget w;
 …
 return std::move(w); 
}
```

I know that returns an lvalue reference of local object is always wrong.
So, returns an rvalue reference of local object is also wrong?

Comment: The quote is confused. Where did you get it from? Objects are never rvalues; _expressions_ are rvalues.

Comment: _"I know that returns an lvalue reference of an rvalue is always wrong"_ This is also wrong.

Comment: Widget& makeWidget() 
{
 Widget w;
 …
 return w;
} This is wrong

Comment: Yes, it is. But you're confused about what rvalues are and what rvalues are not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  - Thanks ,I see, I change rvalue to local object.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Returning a reference to a local automatic variable is always wrong. The variable will be destroyed when the function returns, so any use of the reference will give undefined behaviour.

It makes no difference whether it's an *rvalue* or *lvalue* reference.

Answer (score 4):

When the function return ,local object has been released.

if write code like this:

```
Widget&& makeWidget() 
{
 Widget w;
 …
 return std::move(w);
}
```

So consider the following three sections of code:

**First:**

```
Widget&& w= makeWidget();//w is a dangling reference,variable will be destroyed when the function returns
```

**Second:**

```
void foo(Widget&& w){...}//w is a dangling reference too

foo(makeWidget());
```

**Third:**

```
void foo(Widget w){...}//OK,will copy it

foo(makeWidget());
```

**So answer is wrong.**

### **And Note that:**

Rvalue references can be used to extend the lifetime of a modifiable temporary (note, lvalue references to const can extend lifetimes too, but they are not modifiable)

> Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary or to a base subobject of
>   a temporary, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the
>   lifetime of the reference, with the following **exceptions**:
>
> - **a temporary bound to a return value of a function in a return statement is not extended: it is destroyed immediately at the end of
>     the return expression. Such function always returns a dangling reference.**
> - a temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call exists    until the end of the full expression containing that
>     function call: if the function returns a reference, which outlives
>     the full    expression, it becomes a dangling reference.
> - a temporary bound to a reference in the initializer used in a    new-expression exists until the end of the full expression containing 
>     that new-expression, not as long as the initialized object. If the   initialized object outlives the full expression, its reference member 
>     becomes a dangling reference.

```
Widget&& makeWidget(){

  return Widget(123);//error
}
```

Comment: You're mixing up *rvalue* and *temporary object*. Your first use of "rvalue" should be "temporary object".  "rvalue references point to an rvalue" is unclear; rvalue references may be bound to rvalues, which may or may not be temporary objects, and the stuff after the comma doesn't make sense. References may be bound to temporary objects and then the object is destroyed (leaving the reference dangling).

Comment: @MattMcNabb   Please tell me difference between rvalue and temporary object, thanks. Does rvalue has a name or has long live?

Comment: No. a temporary object is a sort of object.  An rvalue is a sort of expression.  Expressions don't have names or lifetimes. (Objects have lifetimes and may or may not have names).

Comment: @MattMcNabb  I need to re organization of language, change my answer, thanks

Comment: @MattMcNabb   whether temporary object is a rvalue? Thanks

Comment: the expression designating a temporary object may either be an lvalue or an rvalue (although usually it is an rvalue).

Comment: it's still wrong; the reference (of any type) may be bound to an object and that object may end its lifetime while the reference still exists (at which point the reference is said to be "dangling").   "the rvalue generally will be released" doesn't make sense either. rvalues are expressions, they cannot be released. I think you are trying to talk about *xvalues*  (which are expressions made from rvalue references and which are bound to objects nearing the end of their lifetime, such as `w` here ; note that `w` is not a temporary object)

Comment: just take out the first paragraph entirely

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is wrong.  No reference lifetime extension occurs, so the reference refers to a destroyed value, and any use of it (almost)<sup>1</sup> is undefined behaviour.  You should not return dangling references or pointers.

---

<sup>1</sup>: `decltype` isn't really use, but it also isn't UB.  So there is that.  Storing a reference to it also isn't UB.  Also not really use.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `Widget w;` is on a stack and while you pass the reference down to the other function the `w` will be destroyed... Passing the object by value will save the object from being destroyed.

Comment: What "heap" would that be, then?

Comment: Oh yes it will. Most of the nowadays compilers optimize the memory and do not copy the return value just pass it to the function caller.